# Can I show the momentary payment confirmation with smart buttons?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Can I show the Momentary payment confirmation which described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/admin/checkout-settings/#auto-return-the-buyer-to-your-website) after payment that has been done using the [Smart Payment Buttons Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)?

I have enabled the auto-return option and also added the return URL to the sandbox app but it is still not working.

[image: Momentary payment confirmation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. That page is describing the old behavior that only applies when you do a full page redirect away from your site to PayPal.

If you stay on your site and display the smart experience, you are expected to display your own confirmation once the successful capture triggers within your SPB javascript.